# NServicebus Hosted in IIS vs Windows Service

Tags: asp.net, iis, nservicebus

I am hosting a handler inside of a IIS web application. Is this a good solution ? Or Should I Hosting a handler in windows service application ? Which solution is better? What is recommended and what is more performance ?

I use SqlTransport in my configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that can effect how you choose to host your endpoint(s). For example

- How you want to scale your site / handlers
- What permissions can be granted to your web site process
- How an IIS reset can effect your handling code

But in general... Host the bus in both the Web Application and a Windows service.

The web application handles incoming http requests, translates those requests to messages and places them on the bus via a Send.

The Windows service takes message off the bus and does the actual handling/business processing.

Some useful links that may guide you to the best solution for you circumstance

- Hosting documentation http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/ which contains some information on hosting in a web application
- Windows Service Hosting http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/windows-service
- A showcase sample that uses a similar design as i described above http://docs.particular.net/samples/show-case/on-premise/
- Web related samples http://docs.particular.net/samples/web/
- Implications of Publishing from Web Applications http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications

Answer (score 0):

If you need to send messages from your web application then the only solution is to host NServiceBus in IIS, [With IIS you shouldn't be publishing events from IIS.](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/publishing-from-web-applications)

Take a look [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/hosting/) for more details

HTH

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking about handle, not send.

Comment: See Simon's answer above :-)